# The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.x.x <=16.x.x". Got "18.18.2"

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg, strapi

I'm trying to install https://github.com/strapi/foodadvisor on my macOS.

Following are the steps

```
$ node -v
v18.18.2

$ yarn -v
1.22.21

git clone https://github.com/strapi/foodadvisor.git
cd foodadvisor/api
yarn && yarn seed && yarn develop
```

> Getting error error strapi-plugin-populate-deep@1.1.2: The engine
> "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.x.x
> <=16.x.x". Got "18.18.2"

What is going on? How to fix it?

Comment: Unless you want to do your own testing and debugging and manual tweaking of the module you're trying to use, this is telling you that you are using a module that is ONLY certified to run with a node version up to 18.xx, and specifically not certified to run with 20.x.  So, install nodejs 18.x, the current nodejs LTS version is 18.12.0.

Comment: Tried with 18.x.x, still the same error. I've updated my question with details.

Comment: The error is not the same. (and no longer matches your question title btw.) The new error is for another module which has 12-16 as requirement. So you need 16, not 18.

Comment: @Raymond apologies. The repo clearly states there are scrips that run with strapi and is not a simple npm install. Installing Node 18 has fixed you first issue. Deleting answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is now a different issue with a different module.  You need to make sure you're running modules and nodejs that are compatible with one another.  This is on YOU.  Nothing we can do here.  Go research each individual module you get this problem with and see if there's a version that is compatible with 18.x.  If not, find a different module to use that is keeping up with modern versions of nodejs or go to the author and find out what the status if for 18.x compatibility.  This is how things work in the open source world.